# How to unzip files in the same subdirectories but a different folder

Tags: python, file, zip

In `my_directory` I have 3 folders (NY, AMS, MAD). Each folder has 1 or more zipped files. I also have an other directory named `my_counterpart`. This one is empty.

With below code Im trying to:

1. Collect all the 3 folders and the zipped files they posses.
2. Copy the 3 folders to `my_counterpart` + unzipp the files they posses`.

**This is my code:**

```
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_directory): 
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): 
        path = os.path.join(root, filename) 
        new = os.path.join(my_counterpart, dirs)
        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new)
```

I know where the fault lies, `dirs` is not a a string but a list. However I can't seem to solve it. Someone here who can guide me?

`TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the variable `my_counterpart` countain the path to new folder? If yes then why would you add something else to it like `dirs`? Leaving it out already does what you want it to do. What's left to do is to create the folder structure and extract into that newly created folder structure:

```
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_directory): 
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): 
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)

        # Store the new directory so that it can be recreated
        new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start=my_directory), ".."))

        # Join your target directory with newly created directory
        new = os.path.join(my_counterpart, new_dir)

        # Create those folders, works even with nested folders
        if (not os.path.exists(new)):
            os.makedirs(new)

        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new)
```

Comment: `my_counterpart` is just the path to an empty directory. It doesnt contain the sub-directories that are included in `my_directory` yet. Right now your code is just extracting them in `my_counterpart`, not in the directories (which should be created first)

Comment: Edited to answer your question fully

Comment: Looks great, there is just 1 problem. Some folders in `my_directory` contain more then 1 zipped file. Which means that it tried to create the same folder again...  So when it reaches a directory with multiple files, it says: `FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists`. Hope you understand it.

Comment: Just check whether the directory exists already before creating it, added the `if` to my answer

Comment: Thank you men. There is 1 thing I would like to fix in this. I want  to rename the files when extracting them by adding ---> `date_of_file = re.search('-(.\d+)-', file).group(1)` to their names. The zipped files contain a date, but when unzipped that date removes. Thats why I want to add it.

Comment: That is quite far away from your original problem and will not be very helpful for future visitors who stumble upon your question. Attempt to implement it yourself and if you run into further problems then come back to StackOverflow to search for answers. Even the answer to your question could probably be found in like 3 other questions on this site and a sprinkle of python docs. A little research goes a long way